# How to call gmdate() properly in PHP?

Tags: php

I am trying to display time from xml file using simplexml_load_file
i got the time and date there is no problem like this example 2021-01-02T10:20:00Z
this time was in xml url

`<obs_time>2021-01-02T10:20:00Z</obs_time>`

I am trying to use this code in order to get only time 10:20:00z by this code

```
gmdate("H:i",$report->obs_time);  ?>
```

But nothing happens.

Comment: Did you enable showing errors? I think [gmdate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) takes an int as the second argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$s= '2021-01-02T10:20:00Z';
$r = date("H:i:s", strtotime($s)); 
var_dump($r);
```

Because you have the wrong time zone set on localhost

Try this

```
$s= '2021-01-02T10:20:00Z';
$d = new DateTime($s);
$timestamp = $d->getTimestamp();
$formatted_date = $d->format('H:i:s'); 
var_dump($formatted_date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the 'DateTimeImmutable' class.

```
time = new DateTimeImmutable('2021-01-02T10:20:00Z');
$localTime = $time->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));

var_dump(
    $time->format('H:i'),
    $localTime->format('H:i')
);
```

Output:

```
string(8) "10:20:00"
string(8) "11:20:00"
```

Or take a look at "ext/intl". It allows you to format the date language (locale) specific.

```
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'en_US', IntlDateFormatter::NONE, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, 'America/Los_Angeles'
);
var_dump(
  $formatter->format(
    new DateTimeImmutable('2021-01-02T10:20:00Z')
  )
);
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'de_DE', IntlDateFormatter::NONE, IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, 'America/Los_Angeles'
);
var_dump(
  $formatter->format(
    new DateTimeImmutable('2021-01-02T10:20:00Z')
  )
);
```

Output:

```
string(7) "2:20 AM"
string(5) "02:20"
```